# How well empirical data fits to sine wave?

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have empirical somewhat noisy data about two classes of objects: 0 and 1.

I have a hypothesis that class 0's data is following the sin wave pattern while class 1 not so much.

Problem: how to test this hypothesis?

Dataset of one sample: df = pd.DataFrame.load('path-name'): https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbgnivgcww49b7w/sindrink.pkl?dl=0

[image: that's how data looks like]
I tried goodness of fit optimizing error function (distance between predicted by a*sin(x/b + c)) but that leads to incorrect result:
[image]

Due to the imperfectness of the data - frequency and amplitude are not perfectly constant:
[image]

So I need some sort of algorithm and metric that would confirm (or reject) that this sample if following the sine wave pattern:
[image]

And this sample does not:
[image]

I had an idea to try Fourier transform to fit the few sine waves and then calculate the goodness of fit but I fail to do that so far.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: this may be a better question for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

A more sinusoidal signal will look like a sharp "spike" in the fourier-amplitude domain.  You could try taking the FFT-amplitude of you signal (subtracting the mean first) and measure the ratio of the max to the mean.  That'll at least give a number that corresponds to the "sinusoidalness" of your signal.

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer.